# Random file upload with multer & node.js api

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, multer

**for uploading images that could be of any name or any quantity.**

Currently I am handling file upload with **multer** in my project.
I can handle multiple file upload when i know field name. I am storing the path of each file in MongoDB , and mongoose.Below I shared the knowledge with know field-name  like, **image & images**

**in router:**

```
      uploadImages.fields([
                   { name: 'image',  maxCount: 1 },
                   { name: 'images', maxCount: 8 }
                ])
```

now the problem is I have **RANDOM FILE** and **I dont know all the field name**. like there can be 10 filed and each field can have multiple file,
like banner, slider, logo , image, cover and so on.
**How do I handle this case? When i don't know the fields name and number of images in each fields**

Comment: Show an example.  This file doesn't sound random at all.  Sounds like you just need to figure out how to iterate through an object... not sure what that has to do with random anything, or files even.

Comment: The problem is i dont have proper knowledge on this. I have to handle random images like there can be lots of file name , i don't know. above example is how i usually handle file.  But what wiill be my step if i have to handle file when i don't know the name.

Comment: You have to know something about the file.... how will you determine what's just a string vs. what's a file name?  Can't help you if you can't even post an example of what you're trying to parse.

Comment: like I have a api request. its has dynamic fields. I will store a template information through that api, there will be different slider images  . like category slider image, front page slider, bottom slider, toggle slider. and so on. and i have to get those slider images and store them in locally and there path to mongodb.

Comment: But in will not know how many slider file group will be there. There can be only front page slider or can be 10 other slider group too. each slider group will have multiple image,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So The answer was pretty easy. I was using mutter.  muter has any() field.

**any() : Accepts all files that comes over the wire. An array of files will be stored in req.files**

It handles all the files coming, with any field name :

```
const fileUpload = multer({
storage: multer.diskStorage ({
    destination: (req, file, cb)=>{
        cb(null, 'uploads/slider')
    },
    filename : (req, file, cb) =>{
        cb(null, file.filename)
    }
})
})

module.exports = fileUpload
```

Now in router:

```
const upload = require('../middleware/slider')
router.post('/', upload.any(),  ......)
upload.any()
```

get all files in controller to store the path in database

```
exports.controller = async (req, res, next)=>{
    const files = req.files
    console.log(files)
    // files will contain an array of file, all the file you uploaded.
    //to get the path of each
    let sliders = []

    if(files){
        sliders =  files.map(file=>{
            return {field_name:file.fieldname , path :file.path }
        })
    }
    console.log(sliders) 
}
```

So that how i solved the answer. **any()** filed saved my day.